# Получить значение ключа из массива, имея только предыдущий ключ

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
[Array] => Array (
    [linked_leads_id] => Array
        (
            [8814131] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 8814131
                )

        )
)
```

Массив постоянно меняется, но мы знаем точно положение `[Array][linked_leads_id]`.

Как получить имя ключа `[Array][linked_leads_id][8814131]` (сами цифры 8814131) , зная, что он будет всегда первым после `linked_leads_id` ?

Или же получить `[Array][linked_leads_id][8814131][ID]` , учитывая, что `8814131` постоянно меняется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
$keys = array_keys($array['linked_leads_id']);
echo $keys[0];
```